# Django:TypeError : int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' while getting value from the user

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project where I upload a .csv extension file and i give a integer value in the dashboard while uploading the file, the value that I upload must be given to the variable **sf** that is in the `Index` request field, and this error popped up

```
  File "E:\Django_proj\mysite\visual\views.py", line 29, in index
    sf = int(request.GET.get('text1'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
[06/Apr/2021 23:15:46] "POST /visual/index/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67471
```

**views.py** file contains:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method =="POST" and request.FILES.get('file', False):
        file = request.FILES["file"]
        csv = pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=False)
        sf = int(request.GET.get('text1'))       #The error field
        samplingFrequency = sf;
        samplingInterval = 1 / samplingFrequency;
        time = csv['time']
        amplitude = csv['amplitude']
        fourierTransform = np.fft.fft(amplitude)/len(amplitude)           # Normalize amplitude
        fourierTransform = fourierTransform[range(int(len(amplitude)/2))] # Exclude sampling frequency
        tpCount     = len(amplitude)
        values      = np.arange(int(tpCount/2))
        timePeriod  = tpCount/samplingFrequency
        frequencies = values/timePeriod
        plt.title('Fourier transform depicting the frequency components')
        plt.plot(frequencies, abs(fourierTransform))
        plt.xlabel('Frequency')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
        plt.show()
        fig = plt.fft()
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        fig.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
        buf.seek(0)
        string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
        uri = urllib.parse.quote(string)

        return render (request, 'visual/index.html', {"something": True, "frequency": frequencies, "amplitude" : amplitude }, {'data':uri})
    else:
        return render (request,'visual/index.html')
```

uploading a file in **views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render (request, 'visual/upload.html', {'form' : form})
```

**upload.html file**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<h1>UPLOAD</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/visual/index/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}
    <h3>Sampling_Frequency Value :</h3> <input type="text" name=" text1 " /><br>
    <button type="submit " class="mb-xs mt-xs mr-xs btn btn-primary "><i class="fa fa-cloud "></i> Upload file </button>
</form>
{% if url %}
<h4>Uploaded file: <a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></h4>
{% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

I'm adding the **form.py** file if necessary

```
from .validators import validate_file

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(label = 'CSV File upload:', required = 'True', validators = [validate_file])

    class Meta:
        model = SourceFile
        fields = ('file', 'title')
```

I'm not able to get the value from the dashboard and not understanding the mistake here, please help me out here, thank you in advance

Comment: create a simple, self contained example that only attempts one thing - gets a value from the user and then print it out once received. All your logic and unrelated code is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

You're POSTing the form, but trying to access a GET variable:
`request.GET.get('text1')`

Check in `request.POST` instead